# Taleo Export including UDFs

Tags: xml, export, user-defined-functions, taleo

I am trying to write an export from Taleo for a few Candidate fields, but also need to include a user defined field.

I have tried the following:

```
    <ns1:query alias="Find Candidates" projectedClass="Candidate">
    <ns1:projections>
    <ns1:projection>
    <ns1:field path="Number"/>
    </ns1:projection>
    <ns1:projection>
    <ns1:field path="FirstName"/>
    </ns1:projection>
    <ns1:projection>
    <ns1:field path="LastName"/>
    </ns1:projection>
    <ns1:projection>
    <ns1:field path="EmployeeNumber"/>
    </ns1:projection>
    <ns1:projection>
    <ns1:field path="EmailAddress"/>
    </ns1:projection>
    <ns1:projection>
    <ns1:field path="UDFDefinition,CustomField:SR_Application_ID,Number"/>
    </ns1:projection>
```

From the UDFDefinitions entity the field I am looking for is defined as:

```
            <e:Entity xsi:type="e:UDFDefinition">
               <e:Cardinality>1</e:Cardinality>
               <e:Description>
                  <e:value locale="en">SR Application ID</e:value>
               </e:Description>
               <e:ID>SR_Application_ID</e:ID>
               <e:Number>10700</e:Number>
               <e:OwnedUDS/>
               <e:Entity>CSUSER</e:Entity>
               <e:Type>
                  <e:UDFType>
                     <e:Number>3</e:Number>
                  </e:UDFType>
               </e:Type>
               <e:UDS/>
            </e:Entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not many answers on this one....so with trial and error I figured it out myself:

Its as simple as using the defined name:

```
<ns1:projection>
   <ns1:field path="SR_5fApplication_5fID"/>
</ns1:projection>
```